# nginx randomly displays "No Input File Specified"

Tags: nginx, laravel, vagrant, php

I am running a laravel site using vagrant with Ubuntu, NGINX and php-fpm everything works fine on my site until it doesnt.. I get the typical "No Input File Specified" error, the only thing is its at random. If I wait a while or keep sending the request it will eventually clear up.

Here is my config:

```
server {
listen          80;
server_name     site.dev;
root            /var/www/site.dev/public;

location / {
    index       index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    #root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
}
```